# How to transfer data from View(javascript) to Model in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

My implementation in **Model**

```
namespace Project.Models
{
    public class Book_model
    {
        public static string GetJsonFileString(string section)
        {
            try
            {
                string Data;
                string selectedSection = "Home";
                string home = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/Dictionary//home.json");
                string school = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/Dictionary//school.json");
                if (selectedSection == "Home")
                {
                    Data = File.ReadAllText(home);
                }
                else if (selectedLanguage == "School")
                {
                    Data = File.ReadAllText(school);
                }
                else
                {
                    Data = "Default";
                }
                return Data;
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
Context Menu of Selection for Home, School,Cooking
```

**Controller**

```
 [RequireHttps]
        public ActionResult GetBookData(string strSymbol)
        {
            var data = Book_model.GetJsonFileString(strSymbol);
            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

As you can see in my Model, I hard coded selectedLanguage to `"Home"`, what I want is to have a dynamic context Menu of Selection. How can I implement it ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean _dynamic context Menu of Selection_? And why does your `GetJsonFileString()` method have a parameter that you never use. Is that supposed to be the condition you want to apply?

Comment: you can do it with ajax call , on your selectedLanguage change, call GetBookData via ajax clear entire body and append new data to body

Comment: @Zergling can you give example

Comment: @StephenMuecke updated. dynamic context Menu of Selection just simply means a context menu. sorry for confusion

Comment: Still not clear. Are you passing a value of "Home", "School", or "Cooking" to the `GetBookData()` method (i.e. its bound to the `strSymbol` parameter) - in which case, that's the value of the parameter `section` in the `GetJsonFileString()` method

Comment: Currently I dont have implementation for choosing value whether Its "Home", "School", or "Cooking"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it with ajax call , on your selectedLanguage change, call GetBookData via ajax clear entire body and append new data to body

Jquery should be added !!

```
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

HTML

```
<select id="lang">
  <option>Home</option>
  <option>Scholl</option>
</select>

<table>
   <tbody id="table-content"></tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
<script>


var dataTable;

$('#lang').on('change', function () {


    var val = $(this).val()
    var url = "@Url.Action("GetBookData", "Home")?strSymbol=" + val ;

   var tableBody =  $('#table-content');
   tableBody.html();


    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "UTF-8",
        url: url,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < dat.length; i++) {
                    dataTable = '<tr>' +
                                   '<td>' + data.ID + '</td>' + //for example
                                '</tr>';

                    tableBody.html(dataTable);
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Update :

your code can  be like this if you going to use this

```
       public static string GetJsonFileString(string section)
    {
        try
        {
            string Data;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(section))
            {
                string filePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/Dictionary/") + section + ".json";

                Data = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            }

            else {

                Data = "Default";
            }
            return Data;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How can you change the value from home to school?

Comment: value binded to select element's selected value. all you have do is change selected item